# create custom read action for magazine/ journal/ comic object using facebook open graph

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph

How can i create a custom action "read" for objects like magazine or comic or for journals using facebook open graph apis..?
I know we have pre-defined read action but it works only for "book" object, books.reads.